# Smoke effect for rocket in sprite kit

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, sprite-kit

I'm designing a game and in my game, rockets are launched. I've created an emitter, gotten it configured, and when my rocket is launched, it adds the emitter to the rocket. Problem is, the rocket is moving pretty fast and it appears that the particles follow the motion of the rocket - what I mean by that is, instead of the rocket leaving a "trail" of smoke behind it, the "smoke" looks the same as if the rocket weren't moving, I guess because it is a child of the rocket.

The only workaround I've thought to my problem is to:
-Create an ivar or property to hold the current position of the rocket and update this every frame
-When rocket is launched, add child of emitter to the scene, not to the rocket
-place it's position at the position of the rocket
-on update, follow the rocket

However, this seems extremely computationally expensive, to be checking to see if a rocket exists, getting it's position if it does, creating a new CGPoint for this position, and set the emitter position to this new point on every single frame. Also, it leaves very few options for having more than one rocket on the screen at the same time.

Any other, more elegant solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `targetNode` property of your emitter to the `SKNode` or `SKScene` that you want the smoke to stay on.  That property sets the node that the emitter particles will be children of, that way when the rocket moves, the emitted particles stay in the same place.

NOTE: The emitter itself should still be a child of the rocket.

[SKEmitterNode.targetNode docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKEmitterNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKEmitterNode/targetNode)

Comment: thanks, this answered my question. however, i now have another problem: once the rocket leaves the screen and i remove it from it's parent, and remove the smoke emitter from it's parent as well (which is the rocket), to make way for the next rocket, then the smoke disappears abruptly. obviously this looks bad, but i understand why it happens. i assume there is no easy way to deal with this new problem?

Comment: Can you let the rocket go further offscreen ? Give it a long enough buffer to get the trail offscreen.

Comment: @user2391236 you're welcome. I think the new problem with the smoke is enough to warrant its own question. Can you start a new one so that the solution doesn't get lost in the comments here?